# What is the better url structure for RESTful application?

Tags: laravel, api, angular, restful-url

We have a Laravel back-end and Angular2 for front-end.

Which URL structure is better:

`what/:id/action` 
Example: **course/2/edit**

> (I've seen this version in most blogs and it's [Laravel's default convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers))

or

`what/action/:id` 
Example: **course/edit/2**

> This version seems to have better protection from "overlapping"
>   `what/:id/action` would run into an issue if I would have 
>   **course/categories** because *categories* would fall into **:id** slot.

---

*All of these URLs share the same method (GET) so the structure itself needs to be good enough.*

*The overlapping issue could be solved with ordering the routes in right order or using 
`pathMatch: 'full'` but that would mean that the pattern itself is not good enough.*

Sorry for the kinda subjective question, and thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: course/2/edit will be the best url structure.

Comment: @Muthu17, yeah currently it seems so. But I'm puzzled to why Laravel has the other structure as it's convention...

Comment: The default convention is the best convention regarding this issue. It is simple, and to the point. No "real" overlapping of any kind. stick with it.

Comment: I like the default convention better (I've worked with it in the past). But wont the **"categories"** be considered an **:id** parameter in the default pattern if I don't manage the order of URLs?

Comment: I don't really see 'action' in the url, mainly it is resources (i.e. nouns).  Now you might have what/:id/editor to access the 'editor', but the verbs are dictated by the HTTP request, not the url.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use standard [RESTful controllers and routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers):

```
GET         /photos
GET         /photos/create
POST        /photos
GET         /photos/{photo}
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}
DELETE      /photos/{photo}
```

Comment: Yes I know this but what about the issue I've mentioned? The other method seems to handle overlapping better, no?

Comment: @Mihailo just use correct order for the routes and you'll never meet this problem.

Comment: @Mihailo thanks, I've fixed this. `store` must be just removed. )